# select 2 jquery ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the Select2 plugin. It is giving me this error ,

> TypeError: g is undefined[Learn More] select2.full.min.js:2:4800

I've tried many methods but it's not working , Here's my code

```js
$('#medicine_id').select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Medicine",
  ajax: {
    url: '/medicinename',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 200,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        q: params.term,
      };
    }
  },
  minimumInputLength: 3,

  templateResult: function(repo) {
    if (repo.loading)
      return repo.text;
    console.log(repo.loading)

    var markup =
      '<div>' +
      "<span  style='margin-left:10px;'>" + repo.text +
      "</div>"
    console.log(markup);

    return markup;
  },
  templateSelection: function(repo) {
    userId = repo.id
    return repo.text;
  },
  escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
  }
});
```

Json response is

```
[{ "text":"Alka-Seltzer PlusDay and Night Cold","id": 385 }]
```

Comment: `processResults` section is missing in select2 configration

Comment: add processResults but did not work , it seems to be used for pagination of data which i dont need

Comment: Do you have used `select2.min.js` cdn file

Comment: yes select2.min.js is added already

Comment: What should `g` be then?

Comment: Can you check with `type: 'POST',` on ajax section